# Recursive query repeating itself

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a edge table that looks something like this:

leftEdgeGUID, rightEdgeGUID

This table is a many to many "friends" table.

I'm trying to find the degrees of separation and the path between each node to write in another "Node Path" table. This data almost never changes and the old purpose is to see this path and degree of separation data in real time.

Anyways, My query keeps eventually including the original edge ID I started with. Is there anyway to prevent that from happening?

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
 (SELECT 0 AS depth, ARRAY[]::varchar[] AS parents, leftGid, rightGid, leftGid AS last_id 
  FROM entityNodes en
  INNER JOIN entities e ON e.Gid = en.leftGid
  WHERE leftGid = 'PERSON 1s GUID'
  UNION
   SELECT depth+1, array_append(parents, e.name) AS parents, en.leftGid, en.rightGid, en.rightGid AS last_id
   FROM CTE
   INNER JOIN entityNodes en ON en.leftGid = last_id
   INNER JOIN entities e ON e.Gid = en.leftGid
   WHERE depth < 6  
  )
SELECT depth, parents, eleft.Name AS leftName, eRight.name AS rightName
 FROM CTE_SD
 INNER JOIN entities eLeft ON eLeft.Gid = leftGid
 INNER JOIN entities eRight ON eRight.Gid = rightGid
WHERE eright.Name='Person 2 NAME'
ORDER by depth
;
```

Note: I'm returning names instead of GUIDs so it can be human readable to me and I can quickly check the sanity.

My problem is that in the parents array, you'll see person 1 or person 2 in there again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by checking if the parents array is equal to the unnested SELECT DISTINCT version of the same array.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_unique (ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT unnest($1))
$$;
```

Then add this line to the final WHERE clause

```
AND parents = array_unique(parents)
```